# Why CSS pulse animation is not working without any errors?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, jsx, conditional-rendering

[codeSandbox link](https://qub76.csb.app/)

'**expense**' and '**income**' are two states with initial value of 0.
The expense container amount required to be highlighted with pulse animation when the expense amount is greater than income amount.
I have tried to change the class dynamically with condition that checks the expense amount value  whether it is greater than income amount or not, and the animation didn't worked with no errors at all.

income  -  +value
expense -  -value

[image: App UI]

```
         IncomeExpense.js  *Here I have changed the class dynamically*

         import React from "react";
         import "./App.css";

      const IncomeExpense = ({ expense, income }) => {
      return (
       <div className="income-expense-container">
       <div className="income-info">
      <h3>INCOME</h3>
      <h2 className="income-field">₹{income}</h2>
      </div>

    <div className="expense-info">
    <h3>EXPENSE</h3>
    <h2
      className={`expense-field ${
        Number(expense) > Number(income) ? "-pulse" : ""
      }`}> ₹{expense * -1}  </h2>
     </div>
    </div>
   );
   };

   export default IncomeExpense;


    App.css  *css pulse animation code*

     .expense-field {
      margin-top: 2px;
      color: #c00000;
  }

  .expense-field-pulse {
   margin-top: 2px;
   color: #c00000;
   animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  }

  @keyframes glow {
   from {
   text-shadow: 0 0 10px #c00000, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #c00000,
    0 0 40px #c00000, 0 0 50px #c00000, 0 0 60px #c00000, 0 0 70px #c00000;
   }

   to {
   text-shadow: 0 0 20px #c00000, 0 0 30px #c00000, 0 0 40px #c00000,
   0 0 50px #c00000, 0 0 60px #c00000, 0 0 70px #c00000, 0 0 80px #c00000;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your structure, expense never larger than income, also you need to delete the space after expense-field, this code will work:

```
className={`expense-field${(expense * -1) > income ? "-pulse" : ""}`}
```